# AUC for SVM model

Tags: r

I am trying to find the AUC for my kernels that I ran using SVM. When I used the predict and my model and test data I get null values. I need help I need this by 11:59 tonight.

```
L_model <- train(x,y,method="svmLinear",tuneLength=5,
   trControl=trainControl(method='repeatedcv',number = 10,repeats = 10))

test.pred <- predict(L_model, data.test,type="prob")
multiclass.roc(data.test$Pclass, test.pred)
```

I tried to use classProbs = true in my model, but do I have to turn my values to true and false to get the probabilities for the AUC?

Comment: You are expected to do searching before posting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+AUC+for+SVM+model . I you don't find an answer in one of thiose , then explain why and post an example dataset.

Comment: Welcome to SO Bradford Patton. While the people in this community are very helpful, please review [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest). You will note from the answers in that link that in general, questions containing calls for 'urgency' also contain other issues. The comment from @IRTFM demonstrates this. Thanks.

Comment: @BradfordPatton :: You should also read people’s advice on posing Homework questions. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions